# jOOQ tries to write value for Identity column when writing a record

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I have a simple method (with jooq), essentially doing this:

```java
MyObject myObject = ...;
MyObjectRecord myObjectRecord = MyConvertor.convertor(myObject);

DSLContext create = ...;
create.insertInto(Tables.MY_OBJECT)
      .set(myObjectRecord)
      .execute();
```

Within the table 'MY_OBJECT', I have a field 'id', which is defined as:

```
id SERIAL NOT NULL;
```

Whenever I run the code mentioned above, I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [insert into "public"."myobject" ("somefield", "id") values (?, ?)];
ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
Failing row contains (somevalue, null).
```

The problem, as I see it, is that jOOq is trying to write a value to an identity column. The reason `MyConvertor` keeps it as null is because the value is to be generated by the db. How do I make jooq to not try and write a `null` to this field?

Comment: What version of jOOQ are you using? Did you explicitly set the `id` value on the `myObjectRecord` to `null`? I.e. is `myObjectRecord.changed(MY_OBJECT.ID) == true`? That would mean that you intend for the `id` value to be `null` when inserting...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the entire object via `set`, I think what you want to do is explicitly define the columns and values you want to `insert`, since you only want to `insert` a subset of them.

For example:

```
create.insertInto(Tables.MY_OBJECT, "somefield")
      .values(MyObjectRecord.getSomeField()).execute();
```

Assuming `MyObjectRecord` has a `getSomeField` method which retrieves the value for that field.

The first argument to `insertInto` is the table name, followed by a vararg list of column names. `values` then takes vararg list of column values. This allows you specify particular column/value pairs which are a subset of the whole object.

You may also be able to use the `set` style instead, but enumerate over the column/value pairs as arguments instead, i.e.:

```
create.insertInto(Tables.MY_OBJECT)
      .set("somefield", MyObjectRecord.getSomeField())
      .execute();
```

*Note*: Untested, but I think one of the above (or both) should work.

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

OK... How about using a version of your object that doesn't contain the `id` column at all, so it won't be used by *jOOQ*? You could perhaps have a base object without the `id` column, and then have a derived one which adds the `id` column on top for when you need to have that.

Comment: Yes, it is true that this works, but it is something I don't want to do. Making a user do it like this pretty much makes a huge chunk of the jooq APIs unusable for any table that has an IDENTITY column. There is a similar table, for which I am doing a batch insert, which will also be rendered useless and I will have to do this iterated over an entire loop.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem today and found a solution: you can call `reset(field)`.

```java
MyObject myObject = ...;
MyObjectRecord myObjectRecord = MyConvertor.convertor(myObject);

// Tell jOOQ to not write the null value, which would violate the 'not null' constraint
myObjectRecord.reset(MY_OBJECT.ID);

DSLContext create = ...;
create.insertInto(Tables.MY_OBJECT)
      .set(myObjectRecord)
      .execute();
```

The root of the problem is that the application always calls `set(MY_OBJECT.ID, idValueToSet)` even when `idValueToSet` is `null`. As jOOQ record objects keep track of which setters were called, this is different from *not calling `set()`*: it causes jOOQ to include that field in the INSERT (or UPDATE) operation, which leads to the constraint violation encountered by OP.

Note, however, that while the approach above solves this problem, it is not really optimal: it means that one part of the code (the converter class) always calls `set()`, and then another part of the code (the one shown above) un-does this by calling `reset()`. Obviously it would be better to change your converter class to check for `null` and avoid calling `set()` in that case.

But that may not be applicable in your situation. Here is an example: in my case, the converter class is supposed to map things directly and not contain special cases like this, partly because it is not only used for `INSERT` but also for `UPDATE`. So I don't really want to put the "if null avoid calling set" logic into the converter class, and ended up with the `reset()` solution shown above.